# JQuery Append Two Elements at Once and Update Dynamically

Tags: jquery, append

Is there a way to alter the following to make it work?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
            $("#results").append($("<div><a href='"+data[3][i]+"' target='_blank'></a></div>").text(data[1][i]));
            $("#results").append($("<p></p>").text(data[2][i]
            ));       

          }
```

When I add the `div` tags as above I lose the `a` element, and vice versa when i change their position. I've also tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {          

            $("#results").append($('<div><a/></div>'))
              .find('a').text(data[1][i])
                        .attr("href", data[3][i])
          }
```

but in this case I can't target each separate `a` element or the `text`.

My objective is to dynamically add `div` elements with an `a` and `p` element inside. If anyone has any other ideas on how to achieve this I'd be grateful as I'm stumped atm. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can incorporate content of element while creating the same. Try following instead of `text()` function to add content in html elements.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
    $("#results")
        .append("<div><a href='" + data[3][i] + "' target='_blank'>" + data[1][i] + "</a></div>")
        .append("<p>" + data[2][i] + "</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You had mis-nested some parentheses, so one of the `.text()`s was applying to the wrong DOM element and overwriting already-appended data. (Specifically `text(data[1][i])` was overwriting the `<a>`)

You can glob everything into a single string and append that all at once, as in @Tanmay's answer -- which is a fine approach and often convenient.  Here's an alternative, which constructs nodes and attributes separately, and may be more readable / maintainable in some cases.

```js
// This is a strange data structure to depend on. Consider refactoring.
var data = [
  [],
  ["link 1", "link 2", "link 3"],
  ["paragaph 1", "paragraph 2", "paragraph 3"],
  ["/1", "/2", "/3"]
]

for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
  $("#results")
  .append($("<div>")
    .append($("<a target='_blank'>")
      .attr("href", data[3][i])
      .text(data[1][i])
    )
  ).append(
    $("<p>")
    .text(data[2][i])
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Another way to refactor this might be to generate your nodes separately, to make it easier to keep track of what's being appended to what.  This is functionally identical to the above:

```js
// This is a strange data structure to depend on. Consider refactoring.
var data = [
  [],
  ["link 1", "link 2", "link 3"],
  ["paragaph 1", "paragraph 2", "paragraph 3"],
  ["/1", "/2", "/3"]
]

for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
  var theA = $("<a target='_blank'>")
    .attr("href", data[3][i])
    .text(data[1][i]);
  var theDiv = $("<div>").append(theA);
  var theP = $("<p>").text(data[2][i]);

  $("#results").append(theDiv).append(theP);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

All of these can be mixed and matched at will; there's no significant difference in performance, so you can use whatever combination is most convenient for the HTML you're generating.

Comment: Thanks yes this format seems better. You'd think some of this would be on the documentation? Or maybe I should know this anyway..

Comment: It's all just a matter of keeping track of which node is currently being modified -- easy to lose track when you're doing a bunch of nested rules at once like this.